# What is the definition and upper bound on the variable "m" in the definition of the multivariate normal Fisher Information?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, fisher-information, bounds

> Multivariate normal distribution [edit] The FIM for a $N$-variate
> multivariate normal distribution, $X \sim N(\mu(\theta),
>  \Sigma(\theta))$ has a special form. Let the $K$-dimensional vector of
> parameters be $\theta=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\theta_{1} & \ldots &
>  \theta_{K}\end{array}\right]^{\top}$ and the vector of random normal
> variables be $X=\left[\begin{array}{lll}X_{1} & \ldots &
>  X_{N}\end{array}\right]^{\top} .$ Assume that the mean values of these
> random variables are $\mu(\theta)=\left[\mu_{1}(\theta) \quad \ldots
>  \quad \mu_{N}(\theta)\right]^{\top}$, and let $\Sigma(\theta)$ be the
> covariance matrix. Then, for $1 \leq m, n \leq K$, the $(m, n)$ entry
> of the FIM is: $^{[16]}$ $$ \mathcal{I}_{m, n}=\frac{\partial
>  \mu^{\top}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial
>  \mu}{\partial \theta_{n}}+\frac{1}{2}
>  \operatorname{tr}\left(\Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial
> \theta_{m}} \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial
>  \theta_{n}}\right) $$ where $(\cdot)^{\top}$ denotes the transpose of
> a vector, $\operatorname{tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the trace of a square
> matrix, and: $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial
>  \theta_{m}} &=\left[\begin{array}{lll} \frac{\partial
>  \mu_{1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \frac{\partial \mu_{2}}{\partial
>  \theta_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial \mu_{N}}{\partial \theta_{m}}
>  \end{array}\right]^{\top} \\ \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial
>  \theta_{m}} &=\left[\begin{array}{cccc} \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{1,1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{1,2}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{1, N}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \\ \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{2,1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{2,2}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{2, N}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &
>  \vdots \\ \frac{\partial \Sigma_{N, 1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} &
>  \frac{\partial \Sigma_{N, 2}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \cdots &
>  \frac{\partial \Sigma_{N, N}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \end{array}\right]
>  \end{aligned} $$

Most importantly: What is the variable "m" in the definition of the multivariate normal Fisher Information??

This Wikipedia Definition does not make sense as the fisher information is a metric tensor induced by the hypothesis space and therefore is guaranteed to be symmetric. Writting each entry of the fisher information as $\mathcal{I}_{m,n}$ where $1\leq m, n\leq K$ suggests the Fisher Information Matrix is not symmetric. We do not even have an upper bound on "m"!

Also Is K, the # parameters equal to the N, the number of different mean variables?

What's supposed to be the dimensions of the Fisher info for a multivariate normal?

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information

Comment: I suppose that first part is quoted from Wikipedia, so better to quote it. Also, put the question in the question body.

Comment: Is "m" supposed to be the number of mean variables? I think you should have one mean variable per every variance variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m is an index into the parameters.

Yes you do have an upper bound on m.  The notation you show means that both m and n are bounded by K.

K is the number of parameters, which has nothing to do with the number of mean variables.

The dimension is given in the notation: it's a square matrix.

Comment: The unknown parameters in a multivariate standard normal are the means and the squared standard deviations. Is it true that K=# unknown means/2=#unknown standard deviations squared/2? If K=#unknown means/2, then K is related with # mean variables. I cannot imagine a case where you know some of the means, and none of the standard deviations squared, and therefore K!= unknown-means/2.

Comment: @Germania No, K is the number of parameters in the model.

Comment: A parameter is simply what you do not know and have to estimate. By definition of parameter, a mean could be unknown and is estimated, and so is a squared standard deviation. The Multivariate NormalModel has mus and sigmas unknown.

Comment: @Germania You have it right there in your question.  K is the length of $\theta$.

Comment: I don't understand why the means are a function of $\theta$. The means themselves are examples of $\theta$?

Comment: @Germania Yes, the means are a function of theta.  They are not "examples".  Theta has length K, the means have length N.

Comment: Is $\theta$ supposed to be some vector of standard deviations?

Comment: @Germania No.  Theta is any set of parameters upon which the mean and variance depend.  You should perhaps invest some time understanding the notation.

Comment: In a GMM, you have parameters mu and sigma.

Comment: In Maximum Likelihood estimation, you derive the expression of the parameter in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.